# How does Twitter let users open a new window for replies?

Tags: javascript, twitter

When you want to see the replies of a certain tweet, you click the tweet to open a new window. This new window looks like a modal, but you are actually redirected to a new url to see the replies. And when you click outside the new window, it reverts back to the page you were on just like a normal modal. This technique is what I want to implement into my web chat application.

To do this, I thought I needed to use `window.open` something like the below.

```
window.open('new-url-for-replies', '_self');
```

But, this merely shows the redirected site on the same page and it doesn't show the new url in the search bar and doesn't look like a modal.

If you know the technique Twitter uses for this purpose, could you share your wisdom here?

Note: I want to know the Javascript way to do this.

Comment: You are not "redirected", Twitter is using client-side routing with History API (without it you can change the URL, but only the part after `#`), which makes the URL change, without any kind of redirect or reload. I don't know about any library, but you can find one by looking for "client side router".

Comment: I'll look into that now. Thank you for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't being redirected. It is possible for a page to manipulate what is in the address bar using `history.pushState()`.

The [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) is quite simple.

Suppose you are on the page `example.com/test` - run this piece of Javascript

```
var stateObj = { x: "y" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "New Page", "/a/different/page");
```

The browser address bar will show `example.com/a/different/page`

In Twitter's case, when the modal is closed, they can either push a different state.

Comment: Thank you for guiding me to use `pushState`. I found a detailed article by Twitter explaining how they use `pushState` to update the address bar without loading the page. So, if anyone is interested, check [Implementing pushState for twitter.com](https://blog.twitter.com/engineering/en_us/a/2012/implementing-pushstate-for-twittercom.html).